# How to set version when deploying gae java?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

Since Intellij Idea IDE gae deployment plugin does not work, I have to use `mvn appengine:update`. It always deploy to version 1, ignoring version in appengine-web.xml.

How to set version with `mvn appengine:update` deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is, don't add anything on the app engine plugin as it is hard to changes each time the pom.xml better pass the version information from the command line, like this

```
mvn clean package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.version=your-version-here
```

reference document [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/maven-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You can set it via a Maven property:

```
<properties>
    <appengine.appId>my-application-id</appengine.appId>
    <appengine.version>my-application-version</appengine.version>
</properties>
```

PS: I'm also setting the applicationId here, you don't necessarily need that.

Comment: How would one do this if using a **Gradle** build such as with **Ktor**?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following into the plugins section in the project pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <deploy.projectId>java</deploy.projectId>
        <deploy.version>1</deploy.version>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the version in plugin property

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <version>2</version>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```