# How to deploy multiple Java services to the same GCP project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How do I deploy multiple Java [services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/microservices-on-app-engine?hl=en_US&_ga=1.142358388.739934035.1476836893) to the same GCP project?

There are a few mentions in the documentation of specifying the project ID in the appengine-web.xml<sup>[1]</sup>;

> The `<application>` element contains the application's project ID. This is the project ID you register when you create your project in the Google Cloud Platform Console.

but it is ignored by `gcloud` and `mvn`<sup>[1] [2]</sup> (Emphasis mine):

> **gcloud** and gcloud tooling (Intellij, Gradle, **and the new maven plug-ins**) **ignore this element**

---

> Note that while every appengine-web.xml file must contain the `<application>` tag, **the name you supply there is ignored**. The name of the application is taken from the `<application>` tag in the appengine-application.xml file.

The last quote seems to apply to Java 8 / Jetty 9 runtimes.

The java-gae-quickstart project does not have an appengine-application.xml file.

[1] - [appengine-web.xml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref)

[2] - [Organizing xml Configuration Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/xml-configuration-files)

Comment: So what exactly is your question then? By the way, you can also set the applicationId via a maven property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071171/how-to-set-version-when-deploying-gae-java/40131216#40131216

Comment: @TomTasche the question is in the title and first line of the post. I did not attempt setting anything with a maven property yet, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample project for using modules: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java

Notes:

- there is one "ear"-module, which does not contain code, but has an [application.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/blob/master/appengine-modules-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/application.xml). This file defines the modules of your project.
- it's important to have one module (other than "ear") which has no module-name defined (in [appengine-web.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/blob/master/appengine-modules-guestbook/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml)) or has a module-name of "default". This is also the module which is used for configuring datastore-indexes, cron, etc.
- in order to deploy all your modules, you go to your ear-module and execute `mvn appengine:update`

Comment: This solution is not supported for Java 8. GAE does not support EAR files when your app uses Java 8.