# How to set a custom version when deploying an app engine application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle

I am deploying an app to Google app engine standard. It's a Java/Kotlin application, but the question isn't necessarily specific to that. I am using the latest Gradle plugin, and the answer could be specific to that.

Like over all those years, I specify a project ID, let's say *MyProject*, and a version number/string, let's say *1-2-0*. Both pieces of information would historically go into the `appengine-web.xml` file (`app.yaml` for Python). They still can be set there, but are then being ignored, as the deployment process points out prominently.

The project ID *MyProject* must now be specified as part of the general glcoud command-line interface configuration (that can be viewed through `gcloud config configurations list`). The Gradle plugin seems to be picking it up from there just fine.

**For the version** *1-2-0*, however, I cannot figure out where and how to set it. So, on deployment I always end up with a new default like `20170604t124930`, and lots of redundant app versions.

For a prior Python app that I used `appcfg` (or was it a `glcoud` command?) to deploy for, I specified both project ID and version as command line arguments. The Gradle pluging must be finding (or not finding) this information somewhere else. The Gradle file's `version = '1.2.0-SNAPSHOT'` of course is just for the generated jar/war. The many suggestions on the web, the official Google documentation (!), and this site [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40071171/893774) are outdated, contradictory, or both (*therefore, you'll excuse my lengthy, rather detailed post*). Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried releasing a non-snapshot version to see?

Comment: Your question almost sounds like the eventual solution: HOW do I release a non-snapshot version? (It seems I want to release a "non-snapshot" version. This is what I must have read about somewhere a while back, but can't find anymore.) Thanks for taking a look at my question in any case!

Comment: You remove `-SNAPSHOT` from the end of version, so then the final app is no longer a snapshot release.  `version = '1.2.0-SNAPSHOT'` becomes `version = '1.2.0'`

Comment: Ok, just to make sure, I tried that. But that's just the version of the jar/war file. I am talking about the snapshot-like version number/string that app engine assigns to the upload automatically, which unsurprisingly isn't affected by the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer can be found at the bottom of the [App Engine Gradle Plugin Tasks and Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-reference). Just add this to `build.gradle`:

`appengine.deploy.version = '1-2-0'`

Or, as part of the more extensive app engine plugin configuration:

```
appengine {

  deploy {
    ...
    version = '1-2-0
  }
}
```

My confusion seems to stem from the fact that there is the old Gradle plugin and the new one, and [handling did change quite a bit between the two](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle). In particular, the new plugin is more dependent on the `glcoud` configuration. The plugin as-is does allow to set the project ID (`appengine.deploy.project`) in the Gradle configuration, yet, when not specified there, just takes the default from the list of available projects (command line: `gcloud config list project` -- the old `appcfg` isn't used anymore).

However, there is no such default for the version in the environment, when the version is missing from the Gradle configuration. A new timestamp string is taken on every deploy in this case.

Comment: This needs to be clearly defined in the gCloud documentation as it seems like a fundamental configuration. Thanks for uncovering! I made my own [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910776/deploying-with-ktor-how-to-set-appengine-version) regarding Ktor's implementation.