# Deploying With Ktor: How To Set AppEngine Version?

Tags: google-app-engine, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, ktor

### Issue

I've followed this clear and concise [Ktor tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-ktor-app-engine-java8). Now that I have successfully deployed to AppEngine **I would like to manually set the version of future deploys**.

Google's documentation of the [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) file indicates the `<version>` tag can be utilized for this purpose, but also states that the `<version>` tag is *unused for Cloud SDK based tooling*. I attempted to set the tag and confirmed this value is not being used when deployed to AppEngine.

### Attempted Solutions

Looked for way to define AppEngine version in the following files:

1. *web.xml*
2. *application.conf*

Setting **id:**

```
ktor {    
    application {
        modules = [InitializationKt.main]
        id = "coinverse-price-staging"
    }
}
```

3. Searching for way to define in AppEngine deploy command.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @marco for uncovering the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354449/how-to-set-a-custom-version-when-deploying-an-app-engine-application) to this!

*build.gradle*

```
appengine {
    deploy {
        version = '1-2-0'
    }
}
```